# Algorithm for economically sampling method for Gaussian matrix product

Tags: pr.probability, algorithms, random-matrices, gaussian, algorithmic-randomness

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ random matrix with i.i.d. $N(0,\sigma)$ entries, for some $\sigma>0$ and let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.  A direct computation shows that $Ax \sim N(0,\sigma x^{\top}x)$.

I would like to sample from $N(0,\sigma x^{\top}x)$ however, the trouble is that if $n$ is large then this storing the matrix $x^{\top}x$ on my machine is infeasible.  So I'm wondering, are there known methods for sampling from such a distribution without storing $x^{\top}x$.  Or are tere algorithms for sampling from the random product $Ax$?

**Idea:** For example, can we generate samples from $Ax$ if we only know the eigenvalues of $x^{\top}x$?

Comment: The usual convention is that the normal distribution is parametrised as $N(0, \sigma^2)$ where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation. You're using $\sigma$ instead of $\sigma^2$. Is this on purpose?

Comment: Oh, ya its on purpouse but for my purpouse it didn't matter.  I can equally well-take the $\sigma^2$ convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sample from the product $Ax$ in the following way:

Sample a row of $A$ and multiply by $x$. To save memory, forget the row. Sample another row of $A$ and multiply by $x$. To save memory, forget the row. And so on.

An even faster way of sampling from $a^T x$ where $a$ is a row of $A$ is to simply sample from $N(0, \sigma |x|^2)$. This follows from the formula for the [sum of two normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables), which can be straightforwardly generalised to the sum of $n$ normal distributions.

Comment: I like this idea.  However, it may take a long time to loop over.  Would you happen to know of another way?

Comment: @Zorn'sLama Is there a way to sample from $a^T x$ where $a$ is a vector of iid samples from $N(0, \sigma)$? I'll try and think about this

Comment: Ah, $a$ follows an axis-symmetric distribution. So I think that to sample from $a^T x$, you need only to sample from $N(0, \sigma)$ and multiply by $|x|$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Actually, this works great.  Thank you ogogmad!

Comment: It follows from the rotational symmetry of $N(0, \sigma \oplus \sigma \oplus \dotsb \oplus \sigma)$. Consider the case when $x$ is parallel to one of the coordinate axes; it's clear that $a^T x$ follows the same distribution as $N(0, \sigma |x|)$. Now using rotational symmetry of the distribution of $a$, simply change coordinates so that $x$ is parallel to one of the coordinate axes

Comment: Ah, this is very helpful.  Thanks ogogmad!

Comment: I think this is a simpler and more general way of looking at it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables